# Compiling a single .cpp in VS 2008 w/ the Command Line

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, command-line, compilation

I was using MinGW's GCC manually without a makefile to compile a DLL. It's since proved ridiculously hard to get more than one MinGW DLL running in an app compiled with Visual Studio.

I've decided to compile the DLL with the Visual Studio 2008 Command Line, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that. It seems there are sizable differences between 2005 and 2008. I could be wrong, but I think it was telling me that you can't use a normal command line to compile with the 2008 CL, but you could in 2005 with some special environment variables setup. I think I also read that VS 2008 only allows you to compile a project?

I'm not sure about these things but they seem like ridiculous roadblocks for someone just wanting to compile a single .cpp file into a DLL.

My end goal is to have a simple editor I made be able to compile the source of a file and return the location of the DLL it made.

I also need to be able to use the existing VS installation on whatever computer my app is installed on. But I'm not sure how to programmatically locate the cl.exe of VS install without assuming they installed to the default directory. (which I definitely don't wanna do)

So to sum up, a bunch of small questions about command line compiling with VS 2008. Anything or everything would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

-Michael

Comment: Did you try looking/posting on the mingw newsgroup? I find the interface at http://old.nabble.com/MinGW---Dev to be very easy to use. Although I'm not sure about how to leave a message there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use cl.exe to compile smth like this

```
cl /D_UNICODE abc.cpp /link /dll /out:abc.dll /def:abc.dll
```

Look at cl/? and link/? for switches

Call vcvars32.bat to initialize PATH, INCLUDE and LIB before

Generally, environment variable must be defined in install - VS90COMNTOOLS. Find compiler from it